Prior to C++11, the 'one-definition rule' would have been broken by in-class member initialization of non-static and non-const variables. Why?
So, prior to C++11, in-class member initialization of non-const and non-static variables was not allowed.
Bjarne Stroustrup's reasoning was that the one-definition rule "would be broken if C++ allowed in-class definition of entities that needed to be stored in memory as objects."
What did he mean by this?
I do understand that the one-definition rule mandates that only one definition of an entity that exists in memory should be allowed per program. But I still cannot see why the rule would be broken.
My question is related to this question, but I'm asking a different question, specifically for clarification on how the one-definition rule would have gotten broken.
I watched a Back to Basics talk by Bob Steagall - "The Structure of a Program". And looked at some other related questions. But I still cannot understand Stroustrup's assertion.

Because each translation unit which includes the class would have its own definition of the variable

contextually initialization could happen in different ways, which  would lead to a different constructor in every unit. Notethat a class can be a nested type of template and initialization would be a dependant context at site of instantiation.

@AlanBirtles - I'm still not getting it. My confusion lies in how a class member definition int x; is different from int x = 5;. They are both definitions right? As in, they are not declarations. Or ... is the first a declaration, and the second a definition? The literature I'm reading specifies that a class declaration becomes a definition if it is followed by braces. So ... isn't everything then inside those braces also part of the definition? ( I refer you to Appendix A of "C++ Templates: The complete guide" - where there is a very detailed description of the ODR)

Looks like one of those question that can probably be completely answered only be standard committee member or Bjarne himself.

As I read it, Stroustrup is only talking about in-class initializers for static data members. (And the rules there were not actually relaxed much until C++17.) I'm not aware of him having given any reason why C++03 didn't have default member initializers for non-static data members.
Typically, class definitions will be placed in headers because any translation unit that wants to call a method on a class must be able to see the class definition (not merely a forward declaration). But for any one given class, say C, and any one given static data member, say x, there should be only one copy of C::x in the entire program. In order to make this the case, it was necessary to say that the in-class declaration of x is not a definition of x (doesn't actually set aside static storage for x). If it were a definition, you would end up with multiple definitions (an ODR violation) due to multiple translation units including the header.
Even when you have something like struct C { static const int x = 3; } it's still not a definition of C::x. If you want to provide a definition of x, then you must select a single translation unit in which to place const int C::x;. However, as a special case, this particular kind of in-class initializer (i.e. a constant expression used to initialize a const static data member of integral or enumeration type) is useful even if there is no definition, because the compiler can see that its value is always 3, so wherever you use C::x in the program, the compiler can simply replace it with 3. (But if you take the address of C::x, or pass it to a parameter of type const int&, or something like that which requires an address, then you must have a definition somewhere in the program.) If the static data member is not const or its initializer is not a constant expression, then having an in-class initializer would not make any sense because the in-class declaration (which, again, is not a definition) doesn't actually allocate any storage to initialize. So this construct was not allowed.
C++11 introduced the constexpr keyword, which made it possible to have function calls (to constexpr functions only) in in-class static data member initializers, and to have in-class static data member initializers for const members of a broader range of types. For backward compatibility, the special rule that you could have an in-class initializer for a static data member of const integral and enumeration types (without having to declare them constexpr) was retained, but not extended to other types.
In order to be able to have arbitrary in-class static data member initializers, you need to have some way of saying that each such in-class declaration is a definition, but each of these definitions actually defines the same object with no ODR violation. This feature, called inline variables, was added in C++17 (although compilers supported a form of it even in C++03: a local static declared in an inline function, or an instance of a static data member of a class template, has inline semantics). In C++17 you can explicitly declare a static data member to be inline, which allows you to provide an in-class initializer. constexpr static data members were also made implicitly inline.

In case of in-line initializing of a non-const non-static variable, as proposed:
struct A {
    int x  = 42;
};

int x  = 42; alters definition of class A, not of member variable x. It's an equivalent of adding initialization to every constructor of A:
struct A {
    int x;
    A() : x(42) {} 
    // ...and any other constructor of A() gets x(42)
}; 

That's easy part, if initializer is just an integral literal. What if we have initializer depending or something defined in unit? Even string literal night have a problem, ecuase it is materialized somewhere, we might at least en up with multiple instances of same string.
THere must be no illusion, it STILL can break ODR, if you write it so, but technically, you can introduce ODR into any class definition. We just rely on compiler and pogrammer to not do that.
Mainly what we were lacking is defaulting of constructors and a new definition of being trivial.

I don't think that initializing with a string literal can break the ODR there. It would be the same tokens with the same meaning in every TU.

@JanSchultke In modern compilers that's right. Everything written in context of original C++98 and before. I have vague memory it had an issue unless they would define that a string literal is a const char* and possibly a static, "enterred" value.

@Swift-FridayPie thanks for the clarification that the int x = 42 alters the definition of class A and not x. That's incredibly helpful to my understanding. However, I don't understand the rest of your answer. and I think this is because I've not asked the right question in the first place. I'm going to have to study your words in more depth before accepting this answer.
